# Node.js/Azure: upload HTML to BlobStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a frontend which sends the HTML of that page to a Node.js server. The server should then send that HTML to Azure BlobStorage.

Here is my express route to handle this:

```
router.post("/sendcode", function(req, res) {
  let code = "";
  code = req.body.code;
  console.log(code);
  let service = storage.createBlobService(process.env.AccountName, process.env.AccountKey);
  service.createContainerIfNotExists("htmlcontainer", function(error, result, response) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      service.createBlockBlobFromStream("htmlcontainer", code, function(err, result, response) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When I call this route, I receive this in my console:

```
<html><style>* { box-sizing: border-box; } body {margin: 0;}</style><body></body></html>
```

How can I send it to BlobStorage? Avoid the method I used as it maybe wrong because I can't figure out what function to use because of scarce documentation.

Comment: could you add more details on why you are using this planning? Sending HTML to NodeJS then to Blob ?

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT I had to perform some operations on that code before and after sending it to blob.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers on stack overflow, you can follow this one and adjust it to your needs:
[Uploading a file in Azure File Storage using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331893/uploading-a-file-in-azure-file-storage-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a little bit, i was able to send it not from stream but after writing it to a file, sending that file through `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile` function in `azure-storage` module and deleting the file from disk.

I know this isnt the most efficient method out there but it got my work done.

The problem i was facing was that after uploading html code in a block blob(without file operation), its content type was application/octet which i wanted to be text/html. So i had to perform one more operation to change its content type, which i found to be a little difficult due to unavailability of documentation and examples in javascript.