# android image upload to node js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to upload image from android to my AWS EC2 node js server

but in this post [How to send an image from Android client to Node.js server via HttpUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264619/how-to-send-an-image-from-android-client-to-node-js-server-via-httpurlconnection)

my android application was shut down in

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

this code even though I set the correct url.

What is the problem, anyone have better idea uploading image from android to node?

Comment: Are you trying to perform this operation on UI thread, which android 3.0+ devices won't allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must call this function postData in AsyncTask like that :

```
public class UploadAsync extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        //Here you must call the function for sending the bitmap
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Here you can put something to do when the task finished.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Image Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and in your program main you can call this AsyncTask like that :

```
new UploadAsync().execute(bitmap);
```